# Constant Density Function Property

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was wondering if, for any pdf of the type:

$f_{x,y}(x,y) = c$,

we can just calculate the area of integration and interpret it as the probability of the random vector. I know this would be true if $c=1$, in which case the integral collapses into the area itself. But can we say this is true for any area of integration and value of the constant $c$.

Would this extend to the multivariate case? For the pdf of the type:

$f_{x,y,z}(x,y,z) = c$,

Could we "just" calculate the volume to find probabilities?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the joint density of $(X,Y)$ is constant over a region $A$ of the plane, 
and zero elsewhere, then for any region $B$
$$P\{(X,Y) \in B\} = P\{(X,Y) 
\in (A\cap B)\} = \frac{\text{Area}(A\cap B)}{\text{Area}(A)}.$$
Note that the numerical value of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is not needed explicitly since it
cancels out in the fraction shown.  The detailed calculation is
$$P\{(X,Y) \in (A\cap B)\} = {\int\int}_{A\cap B}c\ \mathrm dx \mathrm dy
= c\cdot \text{Area}(A\cap B) = \frac{\text{Area}(A\cap B)}{c^{-1}}
= \frac{\text{Area}(A\cap B)}{\text{Area}(A)}$$
since $c\cdot{\text{Area}(A)} = c\int\int_A \mathrm dx \mathrm dy
= \int\int_A f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx \mathrm dy$ equals $1$.

Comment: Thanks. So, just to be sure, I can calculate moments in a similar fashion?

Comment: No, you cannot compute moments via area computations. For example, $$E[X]=\int\int_A x\cdot c~ \mathrm dx \mathrm dy$$ is not directly related to $\text{Area}(A)$.